# RecyclerView ScrollListener - Animar visiblidade de view

Tags: android

Quero que uma view contendo uns botões sumisse e aparecesse quando eu deslizo o recycleview como no coordinator layout:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas atualmente esta assim, e ele n tem nenhuma animação, apenas some e aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código atual:

```
rv_noticas.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            y=dy;

            if (dy > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onScrolled: " + "DOWN");
                //layoutbotoes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutbotoes.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onScrolled: " + "UP");
                layoutbotoes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                // Scrolling down
                //layoutbotoes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE ==newState){
                // fragProductLl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(y<=0){
                    layoutbotoes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
                else{
                    y=0;
                    layoutbotoes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }


    });
```

Comment: procure sobre animações https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta colocar isso no xml do layout, no topo essa parte

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Depois no layout em que os botões se encontram

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

No caso utilizo isso para ficar igual a primeira imagem, onde o Toolbar esconde conforme o scroll

Comment: poderia detalhar mais sua resposta ? eu mecho em alguma coisa no java  ? adiciono só isso no xml? pois adicionei e nao alterou nada

Comment: Igor no caso o que falei seria para o Toolbar.
Mas acho que se você seguir este exemplo

http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/

Na parte que fala sobre a definição do XML, tem sobre CollapsingToolbarLayout, acredito que de para implementar o que você esta querendo.